# Add a Collaborative Report in my CV

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, cv, grey-literature

I'm applying to a PhD program in Biostatistics. Two years ago I was member of a team crew hired by the United Nations to write a report on security. This report was published last year and has my name on it in the Statistics section. A [summary of the report](http://www.undp.org/content/dam/rblac/docs/Research%20and%20Publications/IDH/IDH-AL-ExecutiveSummary.pdf) is publicly available.

I am considering including this report as a publication but I am concerned that an admissions officer may think that I am inflating my CV.

*Should I include this report as a publication on my CV?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These kinds of grey literature are often included in CV's but it's important to be clear about the nature of the publication.  I would put this after any peer reviewed journal articles and conference proceedings papers in a section titled something like "technical reports and other manuscripts."   If you don't have any other publications, then it may make sense to simply describe the project (and what you did on the project in particular) and mention in passing that you were a coauthor on the project report.

For someone just applying to a PhD program, this will look good on your application and certainly shouldn't hurt.

Comment: So being part of the statistics team does make me a coauthor?

Comment: Looking over the report there's a very long list of people involved in the project including a subset of "authors" and a separate listing of the statistics team.  I think it's fair to put in your resume/CV that you were a part of the statistics team on this project but not an author.

Comment: Ok, so since I'm not in the authors section it wouldn't be fair to write it in the Publications section? And just mention it in my previous job experience.

Comment: Yes.  This is still a substantial accomplishment for an undergraduate student- don't sell it short.